# Can the CNF be the negation of the DNF?

Tags: logic

I've got the following question: Asking for the `CNF` of the following formula:
$$(\lnot X \lor Y)\to \bigl( Z\land\lnot(\lnot Y\land X) \bigr)$$ 
So the process should be like that:
$$\lnot (\lnot X \lor Y)\lor \bigl( Z\land (Y\lor \lnot X)\bigr)$$
$$(X\land \lnot Y)\lor \bigl((Z\land Y)\lor (Z\land \lnot X)\bigr) $$
$$ (X\land \lnot Y)\lor (Z\land Y)\lor (Z\land \lnot X) $$
As we can see, It's nothing other than the **DNF** of the above formula, Can i say that the CNF is just the negation of this DNF?

The negation of this DNF looks like the following:
$$ (\lnot X\lor Y)\land (\lnot Z\lor \lnot Y)\land (\lnot Z\lor X) $$
Is it correct to say that this is the CNF of the above formula?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What you've found is a CNF, but not that of the above formula. It is a CNF of the negation.

Comment: if you can use Karnaugh maps, do as follows: from K.map of the given formula you get easily the map of the negation, and also the DNF of the negation. Then you can use your trick to obtain the CNF it the given formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you *cannot* say that a CNF is the negation of the DNF, because it certainly is not so.

The normal forms of a statement are *equivalent* to that statement, and hence to *each other*.

$(X\land\lnot Y)\lor (Z\land Y)\lor (Z\land\lnot X)$ is *a* DNF for the statement, as is the simpler $(X\land\lnot Y)\lor Z$.   (Use distribution, commutation, de Morgan's, and absorption.)

Thus *a* CNF for that statement would be $(X\lor Z)\land(\lnot Y\lor Z)$